# selecting two different data from different table and display the value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables tbl_product and tbl_sales. my problem is that how can I get the data from two different table and display it horizontally and sum the  "total" and "discount" from tbl_rsales. for example

```
    the ff data in my tbl_products are

    id|pcode|pdesc    |
    1 |1000 |wire     |
    2 |1443 |capactor |

    and the ff data in my tbl_sales are

    id|total|discount| pcode |
    1 |1000 |10      | 1000  |
    2 |2000 |20      | 1443  |
    3 |1000 |10      | 1000  |
    4 |1000 |20      | 1443  |
```

the expected output must be something like this. how can i select it from two different table?

```
    id | pcode | pdesc     | total | discount |
    1  | 1000  | wire      | 2000  | 20       |
    2  | 1443  | capacitor | 3000  | 40       |
```

Comment: Use any of the Join suggestions below and you will accomplish what you want.

Comment: You may need a REPLACE too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT P.id, P.pcode, P.pdesc, COALESCE(SUM(S.total),0), COALESCE(SUM(s.discount),0)
FROM tbl_products P
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_sales S
ON P.pcode = S.pcode
GROUP BY P.id, P.pcode, P.pdesc
```

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
SELECT 
    tbl_products.*, 
    SUM(tbl_sales.total) as total, 
    SUM(tbl_sales.discount) as discount
FROM tbl_products 
LEFT JOIN tbl_sales ON tbl_sales.pcode = tbl_products.pcode
GROUP BY pcode
ORDER BY total ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a join like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_products INNER JOIN tbl_sales ON tbl_sales.pcode = tbl_products.pcode ORDER BY tbl_products.pcode
```

that will make it one table.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by simple `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` :

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.pcode,
    p.pdesc,
    SUM(s.total) AS total,
    SUM(t.discount) AS discount
FROM 
    tbl_products AS p
LEFT JOIN 
    tbl_sales AS s ON
        s.pcode = p.pcode
GROUP BY
    p.pcode
ORDER BY
    /* your call */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select p.id,p.pcode,p.desc,sum(s.sales),sum(s.discount)
from tbl_products p, tbl_sales s
where p.id = s.id
group by p.id,p.pcode,p.desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this too:

```
SELECT 
    tbl_products.*, 
    SUM(tbl_sales.total) as total, 
    SUM(tbl_sales.discount) as discount
FROM tbl_products,tbl_sales 
where tbl_sales.pcode = tbl_products.pcode
GROUP BY pcode
ORDER BY total ASC
```